# What is the meaning of ID token in oidc?

Tags: openid-connect

I'd token carries email, aud etc. fields. Why the client needs the ID token, having userInfo endpoint in Idp exposed to the client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID token represents how the user authenticated and some details about the user. A common use of this token is to create a session cookie based on it.

The ID token usually has a very short lifetime, like 5 minutes, so after the session is created, then its purpose is very limited.

Comment: Client receives acess token in response to authentication. So why not just sent id token info in response headers?

Comment: Using the recommended authorization code flow, the client will behind the scene make a private request over the backchannel to the token provider to retrieve the various tokens.    We use tokens instead of headers to pass the data in a secure way. Also, we never want to send private or secret data to or via the browser.